# Insert an Inline Code with Back Tics do not work in Medium.com

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

Following this Blog:
https://medium.com/blogging-guide/how-to-insert-a-code-block-or-inline-code-into-a-medium-article-7b697bd12e0a

It should be simple to add inline Code with Back Tics (`).

However it does not work for me - it only displays the back tics as characters:

[image]

Is there something that I miss?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use backticks in the title?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No - this is a screenshot from normal text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using other than "Standard US English Keyboard" then medium formatting options may vary.

For instance, I am using ABC-QWERTZ layout on my mac.

[image]

**For me:**

- To enter into inline code block:

  ```
                    [Single backtick + space key] worked.
  ```

---

- To come out from inline code block:

  ```
                    [Single backtick key]
  ```

Start writing after pressing key.

---

**On U.S. Keyboard:**

- To enter into inline code block:

  ```
                    [Single backtick].
  ```

---

- To come out from inline code block:

  ```
                    [Single backtick key]
  ```

*Note:*
When you want to add inline block in the middle of sentence, add  one space before pressing single backtick.

Comment: thanks for your answer! [Single backtick + space key] worked. But to get out I have to press the arrow-right key. - but maybe that is because of Swiss key layout.

Comment: @Welcome pme. Try Different key options may be it will work for you, to get out from inline block.

Comment: Medium has a help screen that can be accessed by clicking the ellipsis at the top of the page in edit mode. For me I had to select the text then hit the `[single backtick key]`

Answer (score 5):

For me none of the backtick solutions worked, but at least for code blocks (not inline code between two words)

**ALT** + **CMD** + **6**

did the job.

For MAC Users:

**⌥** + **⌘** + **6**

Answer (score 4):

It's a quite old question, but i found a way on French keyboard to it : You need to use the **#** button (and not the **`** button), which is fact at the same place on an English keyboard :
[image: French keyboard]

Comment: This also works for spanish keyboards! It's the key right below the ESC key. In my case it outputs this -> º but when selecting code in medium and pressing the key, it automatically formats it as code.

Answer (score 2):

On italian keyboard layout the winning keys combo is `Alt Gr` + `@` on selected text.

Answer (score 1):

If you type the code rather than highlighting existing code, and start with a backtick, you enter inline code mode. To escape, another backtick doesn't work for me - I have to use right arrow.

Selecting code and pressing backtick just deletes the code and displays a backtick. Pretty useless really...

Comment: thanks - can you give an example? - I tried `asdf> and `asdf< - both did not work - what is your 'right arrow'?

Answer (score 0):

On a French Macbook keyboard, if you want to convert text to inline code, press `fn` + `@`.