# Inline Code Using Backticks on Medium Broken

Tags: markdown, inline, styling, medium.com-publishing-api

Relating to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65595747/3042018 I have just spent about an hour publishing an existing article on Medium as I had to manually enter every piece of inline code.

You are supposed to be able to select the text you want displayed as inline code and press backtick, but this just deletes the text and replaces it with a backtick.

This issue makes it unfeasible for me to publish coding related articles. Has anyone found a solution for this please?

I'm using Chrome and a UK keyboard on Windows if that is relevant.

Comment: "select the text you want displayed as inline code and press backtick," That would be a feature of a good text editor. However, I have never seen that feature on a website text area. I would have simply completed editing the text offline with my text editor of choice and then copied it into the online edit box, or whatever Medium uses.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old question, but I found a way on French keyboard to it : You need to use the **#** button (and not the **`** button), which is fact at the same place on an US keyboard :
[image: French keyboard]